# Optimistic Caching Concurrency Design Pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, concurrency

I have a web service that is running on a cluster of servers. This web service does some internal processing, and then may make a call out to an external service that incurs a fee.

I want to put in some caching so that if I receive identical requests to the service (which is guaranteed to happen), then I do not have to repeat the processing, saving both processing time/power and also the cost incurred in the external part of the service call.

However, I am struggling to figure out how to manage this caching when I have the following constraints

- The service is running on multiple web servers for High Availability and scalability
- The request may take up to 5 seconds to respond, but in the mean time, I may have received 2 or 3 other identical requests.

How can I hold off on executing the other service calls, until the first one has responded (therefore available in the cache), when working in a distributed environment.

I have thought about putting in a front-proxy pattern and building up a queue of identical requests within the proxy, so that when the first returns, it can also return the same response to the others. Is this the correct pattern, or is there a better concurrency pattern that deals with this scenario?

Comment: is the external ws clustered as well, have you control on it? it seems to represent a good target to start with, you could write your own wrapper caching web service in front of it

Comment: its not in my control. It is a service we are calling from a supplier

Comment: As in every _cache_ scenario: Are really sure, that the service is _really_ stateless? I.e. a "FetchCustomerDetailById" service is not cachable because an intermediate "ChangeCustomerName" would have to invalidate your cache.

Comment: Ah no. It is truely stateless. Every request to the external call should guarantee the same response if given the same input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could

1. compute a cryptographic hash of the request
2. see if the result already is in the database for this hash, and if so, return it
3. store the hash in database with a "result pending" status
4. call the web service and update the row in the database with the result.

At step 2, if the hash already is in the database, with the "result pending" status, you could poll the database every X milliseconds and finally return the result once it's there.

The devil is in the details, of course, because you would have to decide what you do in case an error occurs:

- do you return an error for all the subsequent identical requests?
- do you cause the waiting threads to retry calling the web service?
- do you return an error, but only for some time, and then retry?

Comment: I would also like to understand the downvotes. 2 up votes (one mine), 2 down, but no explanation? Is there something bad about your solution over @fyr's?

Comment: IIUC, fyr's solution is to have one cache per server, and to avoid having a database because it's a single point of failure. I assumed that you already had a central database, since 99.9% of the applications out there have one. So I designed a solution where all the servers use this central database as a persistent cache.

Comment: I think this will work nicely. We have a very powerful back end database, so this approach will make best use of our available resources

Comment: @Codemwnci There is nothing "bad" about this solution either, its basically very similar to each other. This one only describes a very technical solution mine is a little more abstract. This implies also that JB Nizet describes a concrete solution mine is a litte more vague because in matter of caching efficiency it always depends on the anatomy of the system. There is no perfect solution vor every system.

Answer (score 2):

> 1.) The service is running on multiple web servers for High Availability
>   and scalability

Treat this simply as design constraint. This means do not incorporate the hostname in your cache lookup method. As long as the result is not dependent on the host you should have no problem. I  would consider it to be a design flaw if hostA returns something different from hostB in a HA environment with the same service and the same parameters.

If you want to keep the system redundant you should not have a central-cache. Because most of the times a "central" solution is a synonym to "Single Point of Failure" - solution. The locking is also more complex if you synchronize across Application servers.

How many caches you introduce is a little bit dependent on the cache hit rate and the resources you have available on your systems. The most simple solution is to cache on a per service instance level.

> 2.) The request may take upto 5 seconds to respond, but in the mean time,
>   I may have received 2 or 3 other identical requests.

This is also a design constraint. You split your caching simply in 2 different steps.

1. First insert a key for your identical request if the first thread enters the caching routine and lock access to its value
2. Insert the value after processing finished and free the lock

You need also to handle Exception handling though.

The `locking` and `connection` mechanism might be implemented with different strategies

- **Synchronous** - you just make a Mutex/Semaphore or whatever and lock access to the critical section. Which might end up having some Requests in Waiting State until the lock is gone
- **Asynchronous** - you implement some kind of polling mechanism which will result in a message saying that the data is not ready if a thread meets a locked critical section(as in the synchronous processing). This will not result in many open connections but introduces more complexity.

The Mutex/Semaphore or whatever structure you use to lock access to the critical section **might depend on the unique key**(as long as you do not want to serialize access to your service) you calculated for the identical request.

Comment: absolutely, all hosts will return the same. They are only split out on different nodes for HA / Scalability. But the constraint it produces is that we are no longer in a serial domain, but parallel processing domain. So you are suggesting a central cache, accessible by all nodes that employs a locking mechanism

Comment: the caching proxy should be before the load balancer; if you let pass a request through, you might as well let it run than just keep it waiting on a node

Comment: @Codemwnci I adjusted my post to this question.

Comment: @guido if you put the caching mechanism before the loadbalancer, don't you then lose High Availability?

Comment: @Codemwnci you might say the same for the load-balancer; any role should support fail-over for HA. http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.edge.doc%2Fconcepts%2Fconcepts26.html&path=1_0_3_2_0_0 - http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.edge.doc%2Fconcepts%2Fconcepts27.html&path=1_0_3_2_1